# What’s the difference between a trial court and a court of first instance?

Tags: legal-terms, appeal

In a recent discussion thread one was defined as apparently rather nearly the same thing as the other prompting me to ask what is the difference between them.

Comment: Idk. I hadn’t done any research before posting, however I have now and Wikipedia suggests they are synonymous.

Comment: That's all I found in my search engine though. So is that the answer? Are they effectively synonymous?

Comment: FWIW, I suspect the majority of users who provide high-quality answers won't care whether you've researched your question first and are happy to either simply answer or ignore a question that could be easily answered elsewhere.

Comment: @bdb484 that suspicion has also been borne by my experience; Thank you for the corroboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Court of first instance is a slightly more generic term and is more often used in civil law, while trial court is a term more often used in common law forums, in part, because common law courts tend to have a single compact trial rather than a series of smaller evidentiary hearings in civil cases.

I used the term "court of first instance" in a comment on the theory that you might be unfamiliar with the term "trial court" which most common law jurisdiction residents are familiar with because you might have a civil law legal system background.

Comment: What made you think I might have a civil law legal system background? I almost exclusively ask questions about common law on the site.

Answer (score 2):

### They are synonyms

A trial court or a court of first instance is the first court where a matter is tried. This is in contrast to an appellate court which is where appeals from trials are heard.

Note that some courts are one, some are the other, some do both, and some are the same people with different “hats”.

Answer (score 2):

"Court of first instance" is a broad term that includes trial courts. As long as the court is the matter's entry point into the judicial system, it is the court of first instance for that matter. So, the term "court of first instance" or "judge of first instance" also includes judicial entities settling a matter other than via a trial. A court of first instance might be conducting a judicial review (which is a hearing, not a trial), or hearing an application for various forms of statutory relief or declarations (again, these are hearings, not trials). It happens that most of these non-trial first-instance hearings are handled by the very same courts and judges that hold first-instance trials, so there would generally be no practical confusion if you did not use the terms with this kind of precision.

Here is some example language showing the usage in these other contexts:

- "[This Court held that the judge at first instance had erred in entertaining the judicial review application because he failed to exercise his discretion on relevant grounds...](https://canlii.ca/t/gk0rk#par40)"
- "[the learned judge of first instance had granted a mandamus requiring the respondents to issue a building permit upon an application made by the appellant](https://canlii.ca/t/1tvvg)"

Comment: Good answer closely tied with ohwilleke’s.